# Tor Brower Compromised?

Tags: attacks

My firewall is configured to warn me of any changes to my tor browser when I'm on line.  It also lists the ip address and the originating website.  Recently, it detected a change which was initiated from crl.globalsign.net.  After checking out the site, I blocked the change.  Is this normal?

Comment: Can you define what a "change" is? Tor Browser will change and unless your firewall is intercepting SOCKS traffic, it wouldn't be know the "originating website".

Comment: Did you have another browser open when this warning came?